# Celery is not receiving task when running django project with uwsgi

Tags: django, celery, uwsgi

When I'm running my django project with manage.py celery is working. But, when deploying the project with uwsgi it is not.

Command to run celery:

```
celery --app=project.celery:app worker --loglevel=INFO
```

To start uwsgi, I'm using following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
uwsgi --chdir=~/tender \
      --module=project.wsgi:application \
      --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=project.settings \
      --master \
      --protocol=http \
      --pidfile=/tmp/project-master.pid \
      --socket=0.0.0.0:6969 \
      --processes=5 \
      --uid=1000 \
      --gid=1000 \
      --harakiri=20 \
      --max-requests=5000 \
      --vacuum \
      --home=~/.virtualenv3/tendervenv \
      --daemonize=~/tender.log \
      echo "uWSGI started"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In production you should twist the celery as daemon. I suggest using the supervisor for that.

install supervisor:

```
$ sudo apt-get install supervisor
```

create ini file in /etc/supervisor/conf.d/:

```
[program:celeryd]
command=/home/user/.virtualenvs/yourvenv/bin/celery worker --app=myapp -l info 
stdout_logfile=/path/to/your/logs/celeryd.log
stderr_logfile=/path/to/your/logs/celeryd.log
autostart=true
autorestart=true
startsecs=10
stopwaitsecs=600
```

init supervisor

```
$ supervisord
```

See docs.
http://supervisord.org/introduction.html